# using jQuery to calculate total amount base on checkbox condition

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to calculate total price base on checkboxes and their check / unchecked conditions;

Lets say I have order and total amount

```
<label>Order Amount</label>
<input type="text" name="orderamount" id="orderamount" value="20.00">
<label>Total Amount</label>
<input type="text" name="totalamount" id="totalamount" value="20.00">
```

Then I have 2 checkbox with optional offers

```
<label>Offer One</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="offer" class="offer single-offer" value="5.00" data-amount="5.00">
<label>Offer Two</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="offer" class="offer single-offer" value="5.00" data-amount="5.00">
```

Then I have a bundle discounted offer, with lower price which override the above 2 offers

```
<label>Bundle Offer</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="offer" class="offer bundle-offer" value="8.00" data-amount="8.00">
```

This far I'm good and can calculate total price base on checkbox checked conditions

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var orderamount = $('#orderamount').val();
    $('.single-offer').click(function() {
        if ($('.bundle-offer').is(":checked")) {
            $('.bundle-offer').prop("checked", false);
            $('#totalamount').val(orderamount).trigger("change");
        }
        var charges = $(this).data("amount");
        var amount = $('#totalamount').val();
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var totalamount = (parseFloat(amount) + parseFloat(charges)).toFixed(2);
            $('#totalamount').val(totalamount).trigger("change");
        } else if ($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
            var totalamount = (parseFloat(amount) - parseFloat(charges)).toFixed(2);
            $('#totalamount').val(totalamount).trigger("change");
        }
    });

    $('.bundle-offer').click(function() {
        if ($('.single-offer').is(":checked")) {
            $('.single-offer').prop("checked", false);
            $('#totalamount').val(orderamount).trigger("change");
        }
        var charges = $(this).data("amount");
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var totalamount = (parseFloat(orderamount) + parseFloat(charges)).toFixed(2);
            $('#totalamount').val(totalamount).trigger("change");
        } else if ($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
            $('#totalamount').val(orderamount).trigger("change");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I understand above code is not very decent approach but it does the job.

In last have few more offer checkboxes but these total amount not calculated accurately base on above checkbox price and checked conditions.

```
<label>Other Offer One 5.00</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="offer" class="offer other-offer" value="5.00" data-amount="5.00">
<label>Other Offer Two 5.00</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="offer" class="offer other-offer" value="5.00" data-amount="5.00">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9fq4d506/

appreciate the help.

Comment: So the first two checkboxes would add and the last three would subtract, correct?.

Comment: not actually, first 3 checkboxes are conditional, user either can select offer one or two or bundle, bundle over write the first 2 checkboxes and same offer one or two over write the bundle,, but last two checkboxes are independent and if one or both of them checked or unchecked the totalamount not calculating correctly if later user check or uncheck any of first 3 checkboxes.

Comment: What's wrong with your JSFiddle? It seems to treat Other Offer One and Other Offer Two correctly.

Comment: Yes. I got your point and found a bug in your code. I'll answered your question soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update your jquery code, I tried in jsFiddle and it's working perfect now. Let me know if you need any help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var orderamount = $('#orderamount').val(); // get order amount
$('.single-offer').click(function() {
    if ($('.bundle-offer').is(":checked")) {
        $('.bundle-offer').prop("checked", false);
    }
    var totalCount = orderamount;
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() { // get all checked checkboxes
      totalCount = (parseFloat(totalCount) + parseFloat($(this).data("amount"))).toFixed(2); // orderamount + checked data amount
    });
    $('#totalamount').val(totalCount).trigger("change"); // assign total value
});

$('.bundle-offer').click(function() {
    if ($('.single-offer').is(":checked")) {
        $('.single-offer').prop("checked", false);
    }
    var totalCount = orderamount;
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      totalCount = (parseFloat(totalCount) + parseFloat($(this).data("amount"))).toFixed(2);
    });
    $('#totalamount').val(totalCount).trigger("change");
});

$('.other-offer').click(function() {
         var totalCount = orderamount;
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
      totalCount = (parseFloat(totalCount) + parseFloat($(this).data("amount"))).toFixed(2);
    });
    $('#totalamount').val(totalCount).trigger("change");        
 });
});
```

This is the link if you want to test it,
https://jsfiddle.net/Mitali5205/xpgr7syq/3/

Whenever you click on any button I am just getting all checked checkboxes and get orderamount, after that I just add all checked checkboxes amount to orderamount and display it to totalamount.

Let me know you If you are not able to understand it.

Comment: Can you describe what you changed?

Comment: thank you for the help, I have figure out the mistake in my code but still the answer need explanation so other can also undertand.

Comment: Okay I'll explain it. How it's work. I update my answer with comments so anyone can understand it.